# MySQL: Selecting a fixed amount of records for every unique value in a field

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I am trying to write a mysql command to select 6 items in each category as indicated by the field "category" on the far right. I basically want 6 records selected for each value of category.

Heres an example of the first few lines from a SELECT * command to the databse

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------------------+
| imageLocation                        | productName                        | manufacturer | price  | availability | category                  |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------------------+
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg | Camera Module XF181                | Toro         |  35.99 |           10 | Strawberry Pi             |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg |  Strawberry Pi Extension Kit SG218 | Apollo       |  22.99 |            4 | Popular Items             |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_Zero.jpg      |  Strawberry Pi Extension Kit AU252 | Gorella      | 194.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_2_Model_B.jpg |  Strawberry Pi Case ZM942          | Corona       | 182.99 |            7 | Popular Items             |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_2_Model_B.jpg |  Compute Module Kit GP664          | Corona       |  16.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg |  Camera Module CL638               | Apollo       | 256.99 |            7 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
```

This is command I am using. I am using a while loop the continues until it has run for as many times as there are categories (3 in this case) by selecting 6 items from every category every time the loop runs

```
SET x = 0; WHILE ( x < COUNT(SELECT UNIQUE category FROM PRODUCTS) DO SELECT * FROM Products WHERE category IN (SELECT UNIQUE category FROM Products LIMIT x-1,1) LIMIT 6; SET x = x + 1; END WHILE;
```

I am getting the error

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'x'
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE ( x < COUNT(SELECT UNIQUE category FROM PRODUCTS) DO SELECT * FROM Product' at line 1
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'x'
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHILE' at line 1
```

An example of output I would like is

```
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------+
| imageLocation                        | productName                        | manufacturer | price  | availability | category      |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------+
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg | Camera Module XF181                | Toro         |  35.99 |           10 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Camera_Module_V2.jpg        |  Compute Module Kit GX416          | Belrubi      |  98.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Sense_Hat.jpg               |  Strawberry Pi Extension Kit JJ556 | Toro         |  92.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_Zero.jpg      |  Camera Module FI378               | Belrubi      |  44.99 |            5 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Compute_Module.jpg          |  Compute Module Kit HP564          | Elsanta      | 239.99 |            5 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_1_Model_A.jpg |  Compute Module UZ736              | Revada       |  24.99 |           10 | Strawberry Pi |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg |  Strawberry Pi Extension Kit SG218 | Apollo       |  22.99 |            4 | Popular Items |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_2_Model_B.jpg |  Strawberry Pi Case ZM942          | Corona       | 182.99 |            7 | Popular Items |
| ./images/placeholder.png             |  Compute Module VO511              | Darstar      | 188.99 |            3 | Popular Items |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_2_Model_B.jpg |  Strawberry Pi DB112               | Tufts        |  79.99 |            1 | Popular Items |
| ./images/Compute_Model_Kit.jpg       |  Compute Module DX828              | Aliso        |  83.99 |            3 | Popular Items |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_Zero.jpg      |  Camera Module SZ841               | Glasso       | 115.99 |            6 | Popular Items |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_Zero.jpg      |  Strawberry Pi Extension Kit AU252 | Gorella      | 194.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_2_Model_B.jpg |  Compute Module Kit GP664          | Corona       |  16.99 |            1 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_3_Model_B.jpg |  Camera Module CL638               | Apollo       | 256.99 |            7 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Strawberry_Pi_Case.jpg      |  Strawberry Pi LG178               | Tufts        |  26.99 |           10 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Sense_Hat.jpg               |  Strawberry Pi OW299               | Darstar      |  35.99 |            4 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
| ./images/Compute_Module.jpg          |  Compute Module Kit QR216          | Confitura    |  41.99 |            6 | Strawberry Pi Accessories |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------+--------------+--------+--------------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT *,
            @category_rank := IF(@current_category = category, @category_rank + 1, 1) AS category_rank,
            @current_category := category
       FROM Products
       ORDER BY category
     ) ranked
   WHERE category_rank <= 6;
```